# Where can I find the security token from REST service?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to secure my REST service. The login service seems to work and it produces a response, but there's nothing that I can identify as the security token. When I autowire the controllers, the thing works, denying and allowing the access when appropriate. However, when I try accessing via REST service, I don't see anything that is the security token and even if I did, I'm not sure what to do with it. Initially I thought that the entire header from *login* service was the token because of the `X-Content-Type-Options` and `X-XSS-Protection` parts, but now I'm not sure. Furthermore, I'm not sure that even if there were a token, what to do with it. My first thought was to assign the headers from login service to `postForObject` headers, but it didn't work, as several other things I tried.

So the question is **am I getting the token** at all? And if so, how I should modify my `postForObject` call? If not, obviously I'll have to post additional info, but I need to know what to look for. What **the token** looks like and how is it used with `RestTemplate` and `postForObject`?

HttpHeaders:

`[X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Set-Cookie:"JSESSIONID=C6E1150B1A61082AE77C25EA6C997009; Path=/; HttpOnly", Content-Type:"application/json", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Date:"Sat, 11 Jul 2020 17:24:17 GMT", Keep-Alive:"timeout=60", Connection:"keep-alive"]`

REST test that does **not** work is:

```
    // login
    HttpEntity<UserDto> request = new HttpEntity<>(userDto1);
    ResponseEntity<UserDto> response = rt.exchange(loginUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, resultingType);
    HttpHeaders administratorHeaders = response.getHeaders();

    // call
    request = new HttpEntity<>(userDto2, administratorHeaders);
    UserDto savedUser = rt.postForObject(saveUrl, request, UserDto.class);
```

Autowired test that **does** work:

```
    // login
    ResponseEntity<?> administratorAuthentication = loginController.login(userDto1);

    // call
    UserDto savedUser = userController.save(userDto2);
```

Comment: What are you using to secure your rest api? Rest APIs typically use OAuth.

Comment: Spring Security. I don't use OAuth.